# Installing an older version of Sqlite suddenly returns error

Tags: sqlite, npm

When trying to install Sqlite version 3 (NOT Sqlite 3) using NPM, I started getting the following errors recently and have been unable to install the package.
According to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite`, installing an older version is possible (and required here, since I'm trying to run older code and the newer version has breaking changes):

[image]

I've never had any issues with this before and couldn't find anything similar online.
I have absolutely no idea what the error even is about, so I'm hoping someone here understands what the issue is.
Other modules install without any problems, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with my installations afaik.

Since I don't know which part of the error is actually important, I've added it in its entirety below:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! unpack_sqlite_dep
npm ERR!   sqlite3.c
npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm ERR!   sqlite3.vcxproj -> C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\Release\\sqlite3.lib
npm ERR!   backup.cc
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan_callbacks.h(55,23): error C2039: 'AccessorSignature': is not a member of 'v8' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8.h(71,11): message : see declaration of 'v8' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan_callbacks.h(55,23): error C2065: 'AccessorSignature': undeclared identifier [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan_callbacks.h(55,13): error C2923: 'v8::Local': 'AccessorSignature' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan_callbacks.h(55,23): message : see declaration of 'AccessorSignature' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan_callbacks.h(55,42): error C2955: 'v8::Local': use of class template requires template argument list [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-local-handle.h(190,13): message : see declaration of 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(684,37): warning C4996: 'v8::Isolate::IdleNotificationDeadline': Use MemoryPressureNotification() to influence the GC schedule. [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2518,14): error C2955: 'v8::Local': use of class template requires template argument list [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-local-handle.h(190,13): message : see declaration of 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2518,34): error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2518,34): error C2780: 'v8::Local<T> v8::Local(T *)': expects 1 arguments - 0 provided [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-local-handle.h(331,3): message : see declaration of 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2518,34): error C2780: 'v8::Local<T> v8::Local(v8::Local<S>)': expects 1 arguments - 0 provided [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-local-handle.h(195,3): message : see declaration of 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2518,34): error C2783: 'v8::Local<T> v8::Local(void)': could not deduce template argument for 'T' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-local-handle.h(192,3): message : see declaration of 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2518,34): error C2780: 'v8::Local<T> v8::Local(v8::Local<T>)': expects 1 arguments - 0 provided [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-local-handle.h(190,13): message : see declaration of 'v8::Local' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2544,6): error C2665: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-template.h(816,8): message : could be 'void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2544,6): message : 'void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)': cannot convert argument 7 from 'Nan::imp::Sig' to 'v8::SideEffectType' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2551,7): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.4.0\include\node\v8-template.h(809,8): message : or       'void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>,v8::AccessorGetterCallback,v8::AccessorSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2544,6): message : 'void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>,v8::AccessorGetterCallback,v8::AccessorSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'Nan::imp::NativeGetter' to 'v8::AccessorGetterCallback' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2546,7): message : This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or parenthesized function-style cast [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2544,6): message : while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::NativeGetter, Nan::imp::NativeSetter, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, Nan::imp::Sig)' [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(105,17): warning C4996: 'Nan::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(119,13): warning C4996: 'Nan::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(167,10): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(168,10): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(169,10): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(170,10): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(236,13): warning C4996: 'Nan::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(301,13): warning C4996: 'Nan::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\src\backup.cc(336,9): warning C4996: 'Nan::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\node_sqlite3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v115-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v115-win32-x64 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@20.4.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v115-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v115-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v115-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v115-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@20.4.0 (node-v115 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v115-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.4.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.4.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.4 found at "C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.7.34003.232) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Aci\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Bots\\Acibot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Aci\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Aci\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.4.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Aci\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.4.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Aci\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Aci\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.4.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Bots\\Acibot\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Bots\\Acibot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.4.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22623
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Aci\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Bots\\Acibot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v115-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Bots\\Acibot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v115-win32-x64" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v115"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v115-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v115-win32-x64 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22623
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Bots\\Acibot\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Bots\Acibot\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v20.4.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Aci\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-02T08_55_10_118Z-debug-0.log
```